# Why does wp_update_post causes white screen?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-update-post

I made a custom post type, named "Foglalás". Each post in the Foglalás post type has neither title nor permalink. All of them are kind of Auto Draft after saving. So, I would like to get the post ID and set it to be the title and permalink as well. I use the following code:

```
    function foglalasi_adatok( $post_id ) {
       $post = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $post_id,
        'post_name'  => $post_id,
       );
       
       wp_update_post( $post );
       update_post_meta($post_id, 'foglalas_szama', $post_id);
    }

add_action('save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok');
```

When adding new post in this type, Wordpress throw a blank page. When commenting out wp_update_post( $post ), the update_post_meta is working fine.

What do I do wrong?

EDIT: I checked and no plugin conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When commenting out wp_update_post( $post ), the update_post_meta is
> working fine.

Yes, the problem is not with `update_post_meta()`, but it is [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) because it uses [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) which fires the `save_post_foglalas` hook (i.e. [`save_post_<post type>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)), and because your function calls `wp_update_post()`, then your function gets called *infinitely* and eventually caused the White Screen Of Death (WSOD). I.e. The hook calls your function, your function calls `wp_update_post()`, then the hook calls your function again, then the same things happen again and again and it never ends, or that it ended up with the WSOD..

Therefore if you hook a function onto that hook (or the [`save_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)), and the function needs to call `wp_update_post()` or `wp_insert_post()`, then you need to unhook your function and re-hook it afterwards, e.g. after you've called `wp_update_post()`:

```php
// Unhook the function to avoid infinite loop.
remove_action( 'save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok' );

// Then update the post, which calls save_post_foglalas again.
wp_update_post( $post );

// And re-hook the function.
add_action( 'save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok' );
```

Additionally, as the WordPress Codex team stated in [this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/#comment-843), you should call [`wp_is_post_revision()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_post_revision/) to ensure that the post being updated is not a revision.

So here's a full example based on your code:

```php
function foglalasi_adatok( $post_id ) {
    // Do nothing, if the post is a revision.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Unhook this function to avoid infinite loop.
    remove_action( 'save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok' );

    $post = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $post_id,
        'post_name'  => $post_id,
    );

    wp_update_post( $post );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'foglalas_szama', $post_id );

    // Now re-hook this function.
    add_action( 'save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok' );
}
add_action( 'save_post_foglalas', 'foglalasi_adatok' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation too!

Comment: You're very welcome! PS: I've revised my answer with additional notes and code. 

Comment: Thank you very much!!!